# How to fix MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get some tables:

The migration was:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Products",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Version = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ReleaseDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                IsReleased = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                IsActive = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                IsDeleted = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                Created = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                Modified = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                RowVersion = table.Column<byte[]>(type: "rowversion", rowVersion: true, nullable: true),
                TestText = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Products", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Licenses",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Licensenumber = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                ProductId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                Created = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                Modified = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                RowVersion = table.Column<byte[]>(type: "rowversion", rowVersion: true, nullable: true),
                TestText = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Licenses", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Licenses_Products_ProductId",
                    column: x => x.ProductId,
                    principalTable: "Products",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Licenses_Users_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "Users",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

Now i'm getting while database creation: MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Licenses_Products_ProductId". The conflict occurred in database "app-licenseserver", table "dbo.Products", column 'Id'.

But what happend? Can i fix it?

Comment: You create the entries in the foreign table or you can't insert without disabling the foreign keys. If you don't know what a foreign key is you need to find out.

Comment: @Kendle Thanks for your answer. I know, what a foreign key is. But if the "FK_Licenses_Products_ProductId" is unique, it should'nd be a problem. Or have i missed anything?

Comment: Is the value of productID for licences existing in product.Id before?

Comment: Is the exception thrown by the migrationBuilder code? I expect somewhere you have something similar to `context.Set<License>().Add(new License());` followed by `context.SaveChanges();` and the foreign key gets violated because `ProductId` is `0`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Indeed you are right. The data seeding was broken, and at the SaveChanges time, the Product table was empty. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means there is no row in the Products table that matches the Id of the row of the entry you're trying to insert (merge).

Through your comments, it looks like you discovered a problem that left your products table empty but I wanted to add this:

**Note:** in your model the ProductId foreign key is not nullable, therefore if you don't set it, it will default to 0 and if that Id does not exist, you will also get this error.

This particular issue is what brought me to your question.